# Can't display profile images from twitter user

Tags: java, html, spring, twitter, twitter4j

I want to display the most recent 50 `Tweets`.
All the other informations such as username, the text or the date are working fine. Just the `image` of the author can't be displayed.

When I run the snippet `searchResults.getTweets().get(0).getProfileImageUrl()` it returns a valid source link e.g. `http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/..._normal.jpg`.

But when I want to show these images in a `HTML`-file they are broken and can't be displayed.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Twitter</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h4>These are your results:</h4>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Text</th>
        </tr>
        <th:block th:each="tweet:${searchResults.tweets}">
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${tweet.fromUser}"></td>      //works fine
                <td><img src="${tweet.profileImageUrl}"></img></td>//doesn't work
                <td th:text="${tweet.createdAt}">...</td>  //works fine
                <td th:text="${tweet.text}">...</td>       //works fine
            </tr>
        </th:block>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchTag", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String searchTags(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "tag") String tag) {
        if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class) == null) {
            return "redirect:/connect/twitter";
        }

        SearchResults searchResults = twitter.searchOperations().search(tag);

        model.addAttribute("searchResults", searchResults);

        return "searchResults";
    }
```

**Tweet.class:**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2014 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.springframework.social.twitter.api;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Represents a Twitter status update (e.g., a "tweet").
 * @author Craig Walls
 */
public class Tweet extends TwitterObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final long id;
    private final String idStr;
    private final String text;
    private final Date createdAt;
    private String fromUser;
    private String profileImageUrl; //looking for this attribute
```